# Trouble opening .Rdata file

Tags: r, rdata

I'm attempting to pull metadata from the [CCES](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/21447).

When I download the file that's for R (.Rdata), then load it (`load("/Users/DanielEGreen/Downloads/CCES12_Common_VV.RData")`), it keeps saying `"object is not found"`.

I've moved it to various folders (e.g., /Users/DanielEGreen/School/ etc. etc.) but nothing seems to budge.

In my g.environment, there is the data with 114,155 obs., yet 1 variable is shown which is RDX2.

I am semi-new to R and metadata collecting; I've pulled GSS info before but that's because you can download the .csv file and I know how to attach that directly to R.

Comment: Using Windows? Missing c: ? U need to specify full path

Answer (score 0):

Loading data works fine for me using:

```
df <- load("CCES12_Common_VV.RData")
```

Your RData is probably in a wrong directory. If you don't use the full path then your file has to be in a working directory. You can check your working directory with `getwd()`. Then you need to set the working directory to the folder where your RData file is with `setwd()`.

Alternatively, you can specify the full path when loading the RData file.

Comment: You may want to mention that `load` behaves differently from `read.table`, etc. in that it attaches the loaded objects into `parent.frame()`.

Comment: FWIW, a relative path can also be used.